# regexp_substr explanation of results

Tags: regex

Can you please explain why I am getting different results from these three regular expression? I am expecting the first output in all three.

```
SQL> select regexp_substr(input,'.*') sub from test_regexp;
SUB
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Understanding greediness, not the Enron kind

SQL> select regexp_substr(input,'[A-Za-z ]*') sub from test_regexp;
SUB
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Understanding greediness

SQL> select regexp_substr(input,'[[:alpha:][:space:]]*') sub from test_regexp;
SUB
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Understanding greediness
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.*` will match any character occuring zero to infinite times.

`[A-Za-z ]*` will match characters A-Z, a-z and space, *but not ","*. The regex will only match the part before the comma as it will (greedily) match the first occurance that matches the regex.

`[[:alpha:][:space:]]*` will match alpha characters (A-Z & a-z) and whitespace characters. This means that it will match the same as the above, but it will also match tabs and line breaks etc.

If you want to include the comma and the text after you could simply add `,` to the character class.

```
[A-Za-z, ]*
```

Comment: Thanks for the full explanation and the right solution. I was missing the expression to match ','.